# Xpath: Select multiple Parent if multiple Child exist

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have problems with getting multiple values of a xml file into a html table.

I want to have the name of all parents with the destinationConnectors properties of tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties with the following xpath expression:

```
"/serverConfiguration/channels/channel[destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']]/name"
```

with this expression:

**the parent is only displayed once, even if it has multiple destinations with this class**

the problem is, that if there are multiple destinationConnectors [1..n] I only get the parent from //channels/name one time in my html table.

For example, what I want to display in Javascript with xml.evaluate, if I have 3 Channels - Channel1 with 1 Destination and Channel2 with 2 Destinations:

```
------------  -------------  -------------
Channel1Name | Channel2Name | Channel2Name
------------  -------------  -------------
Destination1  Destination2a  Destination2b
```

**What output I want is:**

- Channel1Name from "/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/name"
- Channel2Name from "/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/name"
- Channel2Name from "/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/name"

**not**

- Channel1Name
- Channel2Name

[Tree view of the XML structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fakf.png)

**XML excerpt:**

```
<channelGroup version="3.4.2">
  <id>e03a0301-4e29-405e-8ee0-f7a47e30d033</id>
  <channels>
    <channel version="3.4.2">
      <id>e4dccb26-b645-4245-bb7e-67e1e4901cd2</id>
      <name>Channel1</name>
      <destinationConnectors>
        <connector version="3.4.2">
          <name>Destination 1</name>
          <properties class="com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties" version="3.4.2">
            <pluginProperties/>
          </properties>
        </connector>
      </destinationConnectors>
    </channel>
    <channel version="3.4.2">
      <id>b33ea541-e723-47a6-af52-e76648c5674e</id>
      <name>Channel2</name>
      <destinationConnectors>
        <connector version="3.4.2">
          <name>Destination 2a</name>
          <properties class="com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties" version="3.4.2">
            <pluginProperties/>
          </properties>
        </connector>
        <connector version="3.4.2">
          <name>Destination 2b</name>
          <properties class="com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties" version="3.4.2">
            <pluginProperties/>
          </properties>
        </connector>
      </destinationConnectors>
    </channel>
  </channels>
</channelGroup>
```

Javascript Query:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        showResult(xhttp.responseXML,"/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']/concat(../../../name, ' : ',  ../name)", "destTcpChannelName");
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "edited/23-07-2019-MirthBackup.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
function showResult(xml, path, head) {
    var txt = "<th>" + head +"</th><tr>";
    if (xml.evaluate) {
       var nodes = xml.evaluate(path, xml, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
       var result = nodes.iterateNext();
       while (result) {
          txt += "<td>" + result.childNodes[0].nodeValue + "</td>";
          result = nodes.iterateNext();
       }
    }
    document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = txt + "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Sample XML would help us help you : )  Meanwhile, the double[] looks suspect.  Seems like you can achieve the same behavior with just a single[].

Comment: Hello, i'll put a excerpt of the xml file in the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following xpath query returns what you need:

```
//channel/destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']/concat(../../../name, ' : ',  ../name)
```

Description:

- `//channel`:

  for each `channel` element anywhere
- `/destinationConnectors/connector`:

  descend down to `properties` via `destinationConnectors/connector/`
- `/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']`:

  select each found `properties` with attribute `class` == `c.m.c.c.t.TcpDispatcherProperties`
- `/concat(../../../name, ' : ',  ../name)`:

  `concat()` the grand-grand-parent `channel` `name` with the parent `connector` `name` element

Will return:

```
Channel1 : Destination 1
Channel2 : Destination 2a
Channel2 : Destination 2b
```

Updated sample: http://xpather.com/o3eFcOCg

Comment: thanks guido for editing my post. I should clarify, I need the Channel name, not the connector name. 

desired Output: Channel1Name, Channel2Name, Channel2Name 

instead of the one with xpath example from my question: Channel1Name, Channel2Name

Comment: if i use `//channel/destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']/../../../name` I get the same as with `//channel[destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']]/name`

Comment: ok, seems to work in xpather but in my code I get the exception: ``Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/serverConfiguration/channels/channel/destinationConnectors/connector/properties[@class='com.mirth.connect.connectors.tcp.TcpDispatcherProperties']/concat(../../../name, : ,  ../name)' is not a valid XPath expression.``

Comment: I use Javascript and xml.evaluate

Comment: can you paste the js code? looks like a quoting problem (i don't see the single quotes inside the concat arguments)

Comment: of course: updated the question. seems that my query couldn't execute this XPath expression...

Comment: yeah to have concat() on the right-side of of a path expression (`/`) you need Xpath 2. You could use Saxon-JS, or since you are using a language, write down the logic around the xpath query

Comment: ok, don't know how to do it yet. but will try with xpath 2 . thanks guido!